# adding Imagick in xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, imagick, php-extension

I have followed the following steps in `http://bytehash.appspot.com/2012/02/Installing-imagick-for-php-in-windows-under-xampp` i have downloaded the dll file for imagick and added this into `xampp/php/ext` folder and included it as follows: `extension=php_imagick_ts.dll`. I have also installed imagemagick and can confirm it is installed as i have run the following command:

```
C:\>convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.6-8 20
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib djvu fftw font
ngo png ps tiff webp x xml zlib
```

when i restart apache through the xampp control panel the following errors come up:

```
the procedure entry point php_checkuid_ex could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll
```

and the following error message proceeds after:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick_ts.dll" - The specified procedure could not be found
```

If after this message i try to copy and paste the dynamic link library location - `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick_ts.dll` and paste it into a document address bar it try to open the file

has anyone come accross this error? as i had the same issue when trying to install msql3 library or just simply uncommenting some of the other extensions in the php.ini file

Any advice would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try copying `php_imagick_ts.dll` into C:\Windows\System32?

Comment: @klugerama I didn't but I will give it a shot, not sure how this would effect things as this doesn't look like the path it is trying to locate the file

Comment: which OS are you using x86 (32 bit) or x64 (64 bit) ?

Comment: @SyedQarib I am using xp professional sp3 x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first uninstall and the things you tried, then  try [these steps](http://www.zoharbabin.com/5-steps-to-get-imagemagick-on-xampp-1-7-3/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is with the environment variables .. try to check the extension directory is there.

Here are few links which can help you setup environment variables:

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path

Still, if this doesn't work then try to downgrade xampp to 1.7.7.

Comment: Thank you for your link however this issue isn't specific to the version of xampp, i have tried this on multiple xampp versions and still get an error trying to load in any other libaries, even the built in libaries that need un commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these .dll's? http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/

They seem to work for most people.