# why php imagick extension not showing in phpinfo?

Tags: php

I am trying to activate php_imagic.dll extension in php.ini i download the extension file from internet and change my php.ini file by adding `;extension=php_imagick.dll`

this line is not already in my php.ini i added manually but still extension is not visible at `phpinfo`.can anyone help me ?

UPDATE: i am using XAMPP

Comment: Adding extension to PHP depends on the system, OS architecture (32 bit or 64 bit) and right php version. Did you make sure all those ??? and while adding `;extension=php_imagick.dll` please remove `;` semicolon. I think your problem here is semicolon which means comment, so remove the comment.

Comment: yaah i do all this

Comment: Did you remove the semi colon from `;extension=php_imagick.dll` and restart your server and check

Comment: can you have link form which i can download this extension for 64 bit architecture ????

Comment: yes i remove it @SSingh

Comment: here the link `http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/` but see `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530549/adding-imagick-in-xampp` also

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the ";" ( semicolon ) character, its the commenting keyword in ini file(s) .

Change it to `extension=php_imagick.dll` without double quotes.